# Negation on the following sentences

Tags: prolog, logic, first-order-logic

I am new to the logic. I wrote negation on following sentences.

```
(i) If you can run fast on sports meet then you can run fast on Olympic.
(ii) If the connector is loose or it is unplugged machine will not work.
```

Can some one check following modifications are correct or wrong? Any help much appreciated.

```
(i) If you can't run fast then you can't run on Olympic
     ¬run fast(sports meet)  → run fast(Olympic)


(ii) If the connector is not loose or it is plugged machine will work.
     ¬loose(connector)   ∨ plugged (connector)  → work(machine)
```

Comment: Can you show the logic you created for the un-negated sentences. Also you should replace your words with letter constants, e.g.  `sports meet` with `A` then it will look more like standard logic.

Comment: Of interest: [How to Negate Formulas](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1164/handouts/120%20How%20to%20Negate%20Formulas.pdf)

Comment: Binning of the para :                                                                                                         (i) If you can run fast on sports meet then you can run fast on Olympic.
(ii) If the connector is loose or it is unplugged machine will not work.

Comment: Your interpretations I don't think are quite right. In pure logic, if you know that `p -> q` then the *contrapositive* is true: `not q -> not p`. In your case, you know *If you can run fast on sports meet then you can run fast on Olympic.*. The contrapositive is *if you can't run fast on Olympic, then you can't run fast on sports meet*. Your second one is of the form `(p and q) -> r`. The contrapositive is `not r -> not (p and q)` which is the same as `not r -> not p or not q`.